# Get middle Y value of the currently visible screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I need a way to get the current Y value of the currently visible region.  I have a view that can extend beyond the bounds of the visible screen, that the user can scroll up/down.  However whenever I need to display or animate something onto the screen, I don't know how to get the proper Y value that is in the center of what the user currently sees depending on their position of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the center y value of a UIView with

`myView.center.y`

Edit for showing center of potentially offscreen items (both on the left and right)

```
float amountOffscreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - (myView.frame.size.width + myView.frame.origin.x)
```

Then adjust the center with that, should work if its off screen to the right or the left

```
myView.center.y + amountOffScreen
```

Comment: I need the center of the screen that is currently visible.  If the UIView extends beyond the bounds of the window, this value would be incorrect

Comment: float amountOffscreen = 
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - (myView.frame.size.width + myView.frame.origin.x)

Then adjust the center with that, should work if its off screen to the right or the left
myView.center.y + amountOffScreen